# Angular 6 custom validation return type

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have this code in my project for custom validation but I am unable to understand what does: `(group: FormGroup) => ValidationResult` mean here?

I understand: `(group: FormGroup)` means return type but then what does `=> ValidationResult` mean here?

```
static comparePasswords(passwordKey: string, confirmPasswordKey: string): (group: FormGroup) => ValidationResult {
    return (group: FormGroup): ValidationResult => {
      const password = group.controls[passwordKey];
      const confirmPassword = group.controls[confirmPasswordKey];
      if (password.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
        return { mismatchedPasswords: true };
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full return type is `(group: FormGroup) => ValidationResult`. That is, the return type is a function that takes a `FormGroup` argument and returns a `ValidationResult`.

This is true since you are indeed *returning* a function that takes a `FormGroup` and returns a `ValidationResult`. The return type of the internal function is `ValidationResult`.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand : (group: FormGroup) means return type but then what does => ValidationResult mean here?

No. The return type is `(group: FormGroup) => ValidationResult`

Which means that the `comparePasswords` method returns a function that takes a `FormGroup` as argument and returns a `ValidationResult`. I.e. it's a FormGroup validator.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this code like the following :

```
{functionName}( {params}[] ) : {returnType} {
    {functionBody}
}
```

Where your functionName is `comparePasswords` 
Your params is `passwordKey: string, confirmPasswordKey: string` 
your returnType is `(group: FormGroup) => ValidationResult`

The type returned by your function is also a function.

When you execute `comparePasswords`, you get a function back.

If you execute this function, passing it a `FormGroup`, you will get a `ValidationResult`

Answer (score 0):

In this block, it is returning a function which accepts an argument of type `FormGroup` and returns `ValidationResult`

Usually, in custom validation, we usually return null if the validation succeeds and return a key value pair denoted by type `{[key:string]:string}`

This key is used in the errors collection which you can use to validate whether your validation failed or succeeded